# Straighten a microscopy sample

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have to find a method to straighten my sample by using Python and OpenCV.

Currently, I only cropped the image by using contour detection, but in this project some samples are not straight. Here is my code for cropping the image :

```py
img = cv.imread('Samples/348A_10_200X.tif')
#cv.imshow('Original Sample ', img)

#################### Image processing ####################

# Resized the images

img_resized = cv.resize(img, dsize=[1080,920]) 
# cv.imshow('Sample resized', img_resized)

# Convert to GrayScale
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_sample = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# cv.imshow('Grayscaled sample', img_gray)


# Treshold the image to find their countour

blur = cv.GaussianBlur(img_gray,(3,3),0)
# cv.imshow('Blur',blur)
ret2, img_tresh_otsu = cv.threshold(blur,0,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY+cv.THRESH_OTSU)
# cv.imshow('Threshed Sample', img_tresh_otsu)

#Contour detection


cont,_= cv.findContours(img_tresh_otsu,cv.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
img_cont=cv.drawContours(img_gray, cont, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
# cv.imshow('Img_cont', img_cont)

#Crop with the contour detection

c = max(cont, key=cv.contourArea)
x,y,w,h=cv.boundingRect(c)
rect = cv.rectangle(img_gray,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0), 1)

img_cropped = img_sample[y+2:y+h-6,x:x+w]
```

And the image :

[image: Sample]

Comment: I change the image to show you the problem of sample

Comment: So what is the goal? Do you want to crop off the dark regions at the top and bottom? And before cropping you want to make sure those edges are straight. But rotating the image you will add slanted edges on the sides of the image...

Comment: @ClémentBadet "*a method to straighten sample*", have you tried [warp_affine](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d61/tutorial_warp_affine.html)?